# Installing a library (Perl::Critic) requiring a newer Module::Build

Tags: linux, perl

Hoes does one install a library (Perl::Critic) if the installed Module::Build is older than the version the library requires? (Perl::Critic requires Module::Build instead of ExtUtils::MakeMaker)

I can't update the current perl because the perl we are using is for production. Thus we can't update it at the perl compiler itself because there is a risk.

The current perl compiler has a 0.3 version of the Module::Build. And the Perl::Critic module requires a 0.42 version.

Can you guys help me if there is another way around to solve my problem. Except for installing a new Perl.

Note: The only way we could install new libs/modules externally(not at the perl compiler itself) is only by offline installation.

Comment: Just install a newer Module::Build. No need to install a new version of Perl to do that. In fact, Module::Build doesn't even come with Perl anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can you guys help me if there is another way around to solve my
>   problem. Except for installing a new Perl.
>
> Note: The only way we could install new libs/modules externally(not at
>   the perl compiler itself) is only by offline installation.

You can download the module and it's dependencies and install them manually, without having to install a new version of Perl.

You could also create a [minicpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CPAN-Mini/bin/minicpan) which you can then use off line, and install modules via [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/Menlo/script/cpanm-menlo)/[cpan](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CPAN/scripts/cpan) in the usual manner:

```
cpanm Perl::Critic
```